# Sending a table to a JSON

Tags: python, html, sql, json

I want to build a live app that displays a table like this:

```
Machine  Production  Scanned  Delta
Mach 1     2500      1000     1500
Mach 2     1500      1300     200
Mach 3     6500      5000     1500
Mach 4     7000      6800     200
Mach 5     200       180      20
```

This is the result of a query.
So far I've build a flask server, wrote the query and made a function that runs the scripts every 2 minutes.

I am a little stuck because I don't know how to send all of the above query result to a JSON and then do the HTML(don't even know if making a JSON is the correct approach).
I would be very grateful if someone can guide me in the right direction.
Don't want you guys to write the code, just same guidance.

Comment: use [datatables](https://datatables.net/), with that you can easily integrate refresh table with ajax!

Comment: JSON is format and which means it is abstract. So, please explain what "a JSON" exactly stands for.

Answer (score 0):

You can call query  as json format from sql [`Json Format From Sql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server) After call this method from front-end via ajax or own method. After you can show data(json) on html.

Answer (score 0):

Example: 
cursor.execute("SELECT earnings, date FROM table")

do:
json_string = json.dumps(cursor.fetchall())

you'll get an array of arrays...

```
[["earning1", "date1"], ["earning2", "date2"], ...]
```